# VUE UI начал выдавать ошибки

Tags: vue.js

После успешной установки vue проекта через vue-cli пытаюсь установить vue-router через vue ui интерфейс, при нажатии на кнопку установки vue-router Соединение в Vue ui прерывается и в консоли выдается ошибка:

```
 ERROR  Error: Cannot resolve plugin router from package.json. Did you forget to install it?
Error: Cannot resolve plugin router from package.json. Did you forget to install it?
    at invoke (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\lib\invoke.js:58:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Ещё днем всё работало без проблем, сейчас возникла проблема. Как исправить?

Comment: Напишите в консоли `npm i vue-router`

Answer (score 2):

Возможно это временные проблемы.

Vuex и Vue Router получает некоторые изменения, а Vue UI часто обновляется. В частности появились плагины (не путать с зависимостями/компонентами) для Vuex и Router которые пока не обязательны, но рекомендованы.

Возможно из-за этого через UI не получается что-то поставить, так-как UI не очень стабильный и пытается поставить всё самое новое, но не всегда делает это хорошо.

У вас в логе написано:  **Cannot resolve plugin**, что говорит на прямую о проблеме именно с плагином.

Попробуйте через консоль выполнить эту команду:

```
$ vue add router
```

По идее она установит и плагин и компонент роутера и изменит ваши существующие файлы.

**Перед этим не забудьте закоммитить изменения или сделать бэкап файлов, так-как команда vue add router изменит ваши App.vue, main.js и добавит файл router.js.**

Если вдруг компонент роутера не установится вместе с этой командой, и в package.json не появится vue-router, то его можно отдельно доустановить прописав:

```
$ npm i vue-router
```

Конечный Package.json должен выглядеть так:

```
...
"dependencies": {
   ...
   "vue-router": "^3.2.0"
   ...
},
"devDependencies": {
   ...
   "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.3.1"
   ...
}
```

**На самом деле если вы используете Vue 2, то вам для работы плагин не нужен, достаточно просто в консоли прописать установив только компонент:**

```
npm i vue-router
```

А потом вручную настроить main.js вот так:

```
import Vue from "vue"
import App from "@/app/App"
import router from "@/app/router"

...

new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app")
```

и создать файл router.js
c таким кодом (в этом примере настроен исторический режим и страницы загружаются асинхронно):

```
import Vue from "vue"
import Router from "vue-router"
Vue.use(Router)
export default new Router({
    mode: "history",
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/",
            name: "start",
            component: () => import("@/Start")
        },
        {
            path: "*",
            name: "notfound",
            component: () => import("@/NotFound")
        }
    ]
})
```